# Dry length of buoy in OrcaFlex

Tags: simulation

I use a software package called OrcaFlex to model the behavior of a buoy in ocean waves.   I would like to share OrcaFlex questions in this forum - hope some users are out there!   Here is a starter question:   For a 6D buoy, I extracted the 'Dry Length' after the simulation completed.  The value of the Dry Length sometimes slightly exceeds the actual height of the buoy, even though this would not seem to be possible given the formula from the manual, Dry Length = (cylinder length) × (cylinder volume above surface) / (cylinder total volume).  Any insights?

Comment: When you have a query about how the software works, please contact Orcina and ask us. We'll be delighted to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That app may be a bit specialised for these 'ere parts, but you never know! A quick bit of Googling led me to the forums at boatdesign.net where some Orcaflex users seem to participate:

http://www.boatdesign.net

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  I have been trying to find the right home for OrcaFlex questions for some time.  The Boat Design forum is much broader than just OrcaFlex software questions, but is probably the best bet.